# Checking the length of a part of a dataframe in conditional row selection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
    first   second  third
1     2       2       1
2     2       1       0
3     3       4       5
4     4       6       3
5     5       4       3
6     8       8       4
7     3       4       2
8     5       6       6
```

and could be created with the code:

```py
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'first': [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5], 
        'second': [2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 8, 4, 6], 
        'third': [1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6]
    }
)
```

I want to select the rows in which the value of the second column is more than the value of the first column and at the same time the values in the third column are less than the values in the second column for ***k*** consecutive rows where the last row of these ***k*** consecutive rows is exactly before the row in which the value of the second column is more than the value of the first column, and ***k*** could be any integer between 2 and 4 (closed interval).

So, the output should be rows:
`3, 7, 8`

To get the above-mentioned result using conditional row selection in pandas, I know I should write a code like this:

```py
dataframe[(dataframe['first'] < dataframe['second']) & (second_condition)].index
```

But I don't know what to write for the ***second_condition*** which I have explained above. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is K rolled over i case we reach end of the dataframe?

Comment: maybe you can clarify this by centring your question in the second condition and remove all related to the first, which you have already solved. another question: which is the *k* for the given output (rows 3, 7, 8)? Consider adding the example as an easy to copy-paste dataframe (I can't edit the question at the moment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to calculate the `rolling` `sum` on a boolean mask to find out the number of values in `k` previous rows where `third` column is less than the `second` column

```
k = 2
m1 = df['second'].gt(df['first'])
m2 = df['third'].lt(df['second']).shift(fill_value=0).rolling(k).sum().eq(k)
```

---

```
print(df[m1 & m2])

   first  second  third
3      3       4      5
7      3       4      2
8      5       6      6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited the question and clarified that the value of k could be any integer between 2 and 4. Is there a way not to create a for loop on the values of k and just write the code using pure pandas?

Comment: This will work with any value of `k` and I don't see any for-loop here?

Comment: Yes but I mean I should check k=2, k=3, and k=4 at the same time without any for-loop, not just checking a single fixed value of k (for example k=2). I hope I have made my point more complete this time.

Comment: In that case why not use k=4, it will automatically cover the conditions for k=3 and 2?

Comment: If I set k=4 and the run your code, it will return just the 8th row. But as described in the question the output should be rows: 3, 7, 8. So if I just consider k=4, the code will just check if 4 consecutive rows have values in the third column less then the values in the second column, but it doesn't consider if there is such condition for exactly 2 consecutive rows. More clearly, first, I should check the condition for k=2, if the condition is not met then check the condition for k=3, and if again the condition is not met, check the condition for k=4.  Any idea?

Comment: @Mahdi Why don't you want to use for-loop in the code? Are you concerned about the performance? What is the size of your dataframe?

Comment: Also I think simply using `k=2` would suffice for your problem.

Comment: Exactly, performance is my priority. At the moment, my dataframe just contains 3000 rows but each day, a bunch of rows will be appended. So if there is a way not to use for-loop it will be my choice.

Comment: And you said using ```k=2``` would be the way, but if I consider an upper bound for the value of ```k``` (for example k=4), I think choosing ```k=2``` will not meet the upper bound condition.

Comment: But as you said in the comment you always want to start from `k=2` so if the condition for lets say `k=2`  or `k=3` is satisfied then in that case upper bound would not matter anyway..

Comment: Thinking more carefully, I notice that you are right, and checking values more than ```k=2``` would be useless if the condition is not met for ```k=2```. Thanks a lot for your answer and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

I will center my answer in the second part of your question. You need to use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function to compare. It allows you to shift rows.

Assuming your `k` is fixed at 2, you should do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'first': [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5], 
        'second': [2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 8, 4, 6], 
        'third': [1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 6]
    }
)

# this is the line
df[(df['third'] < df['second'].shift(1)) & (df['third'] < df['second'].shift(2))]
```

What's going on?

Start comparing `'third'` with previous value of `'second'` by shifting one row, and then shift it two places in a second condition.

Note this only works for fixed values of `k`. What if `k` is variable?

In such case, you need to write your condition dynamically. The following code assumes that condition must be met **for all values of `n` in [1,k]**

```py
k = 2  # pick any k > 1

df[~pd.concat([df['third'] < df['second'].shift(n) for n in range(1, k+1)]).any(level=0)].index
```

### What's going on here?: Long answer

first, we check using the `shift` trick, which are the rows that meet your criteria for every value of n in [1, k]:

```py
In [1]: [df['third'] < df['second'].shift(n) for n in range(1, k+1)]
out[1]: 
[0    False
 1     True
 2    False
 3     True
 4     True
 5    False
 6     True
 7    False
 dtype: bool,
 0    False
 1    False
 2    False
 3    False
 4     True
 5     True
 6     True
 7     True
 dtype: bool]
```

then, we concatenate them to create a single dataframe, with a column for each of the k values.

```py
In [2]: pd.concat([df['third'] < df['second'].shift(n) for n in range(1, k+1)])
Out[2]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
```

finally, we pick to use as index all rows that meets the criteria for **any** column (i.e. value of n). So: if it is true for any n, we will return it:

```py
In [3]: pd.concat([df['third'] < df['second'].shift(n) for n in range(1, k+1)]).any(level=0)
Out[3]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Then, all you need to do is to project over your original dataframe and pick up the index.

```py
In [3]: df[~pd.concat([df['third'] < df['second'].shift(n) for n in range(1, k+1)]).any(level=0)].index
Out[3]: Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
```

### Final note

If the criteria must be met for **all** the values n in [1, k], then replace `.any` with `.all`.

Comment: I think the given answer cover this case. Otherwise, please, tell me why not

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks. But I'm curious is there a way not to include any for-loop in the code? Have you any idea?

Comment: assuming k is fixed, my first approach works without any for. However, it is not as good, since if you want to try a new k for any reason, you need to change de code. I think the best approach without any for, is the one given by @Shubham Sharma

Answer (score 1):

```
# First condition is easy
cond1 = df["second"] > df["first"]

# Since the second condition compare the second and third column, let's compute
# the result before hand for convenience
s = df["third"] < df["second"]

# Now we are gonna run a rolling window over `s`. What we want is that the
# previous `k` rows of `s` are all True.
# A rolling window always ends on the current row but you want it to end on the
# previous row. So we will increase the window size by 1 and exclude the last
# element from comparison.
all_true = lambda arr: arr[:-1].all()

cond2_with_k_equal_2 = s.rolling(3).apply(all_true, raw=True)
cond2_with_k_equal_3 = s.rolling(4).apply(all_true, raw=True)
cond2_with_k_equal_4 = s.rolling(5).apply(all_true, raw=True)
cond2 = cond2_with_k_equal_2 | cond2_with_k_equal_3 | cond2_with_k_equal_4

# Or you can consolidate them into a loop
cond2 = pd.Series(False, df.index)
for k in range(2,5):
    cond2 |= s.rolling(k+1).apply(all_true, raw=True)

# Get the result
df[cond1 & cond2]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks. But I'm curious is there a way not to include any for-loop in the code? Have you any idea?